# What is the alternate way to eliminate our Bad Karmas equal in doing Penance?

Tags: scripture, karma, dharma

- **Penanace** is said to be a major way to eliminate our Bad Karmas.
- In **Today's Life** it is hard to do Penance for some reasons.

**MY QUESTION :**

- Is there any **Other method** for eliminating our Bad Karmas **Equal** to doing a penance ?

Comment: "In Today's Life it is hard to do Penance for some reasons". This is not correct. We can do Tapas in current times too. Not speaking lies for 12 years can also be considered as tapas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer "Not speaking lies for 12 years" - why not 11 or 13? Whoever came up with this random number?

Comment: Satsangam with Mahatmas

Comment: @sv, it is not a random number. 12 has special significance in various facets - dvadasha nama in achamanam, 12 rashis, 12 alwars, 12 months etc. It takes 12 years for Guru (Jupiter) to complete one revolution around sun, so that is 1-samvatsara for Bruhaspati (guru of devas). So if someone does penance like 'speaking truth for 12 years', or 'brahmacharya for 12 years', that is minimum amount of time needed for siddhi.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, yes, if you speak truth for 12 years, whatever you say after that will automatically become true. If you don't injure any animal for 12 years, even tigers and lions will be calm in front of you after that. Similarly for brahmacharya and non accepting gifts, there are siddhis for each of them if done for 12 years.

Comment: @ram Yes. I read somewhere about this but don't know exact scriptural references. Swami Vivekanda also said those who follow celibacy and Brahmacharya for 12 years will get Siddhis.

Comment: @sv. When you are on Religious or Dharmic site, you can't ridicule beliefs here. If you don't believe in God or such things, it's your problem. You can't say things here as "random" and "fake" and all. If don't like things here, don't participate. This site doesn't need any atheistic person who feels who is correcting things.

Comment: Just read Satya Narayan Katha one time and you will get answer of your question. Trust me you won't regret but instead you will pleased that you read it. You will get easiest way of getting moksha with help of this katha and its also not big, so reading it won't take much time.

Comment: @sv " things in scriptures that are genuinely wrong "   only a rishi can challenge scripture. Not you or I who have neither studied it in full nor have the intellectual wherewithal (which at a minimum requires the study of logic, epistemology etc. ) to analyse it nor  powers of divination. We have neither the intellectual authority nor spiritual high ground to do so.

Comment: In kali yuga, nama sankeertanam is the single most effective method to attain salvation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Manu Smriti 11.227. By confession, by repentance, by austerity, and by
>   reciting (the Veda) a sinner is freed from guilt, and in case no other
>   course is possible, by liberality.

So, if you are not willing to do penance or austerity then charity is the best way along with confessions and repentance. All these remove bad karmas or sins as per the above verse.

And, specially in Kali Yuga charity or danam is most effective as the following verse from Parashara Smriti says:

> [image]
>
> Tapah Param Krita Yuge TretAyAm GyAnamuchayathe | DwApare YajnamevAhuh
>   DAnameva Kalau Yuge ||
>
> ..............
>
> 23. " Self-mortification is the rule in the Krita age ; knowledge is said (to be the same) in the Treta ; in the Dvapara, (they) say
>       sacrifice (to the gods to be) the sole (rule) ; **and charity alone in
>       the Kali age.**

So, instead of adopting the other paths which were more suitable for the previous yugas, one can adopt charity as an effective measure for removing sins in the current yuga.

And, among all kinds of charity, one charity stands out, viz: the one called  **Tula Purusha** which is described in the following verse :

> 80. The chandrayana penance, the eating of unripe barley, **the form of making a gift, called the Tulapurusha, [I, e., making a gift of such a
>       quantity of any substance as is equal in weight to a male human
>       being]**, and the act of walking behind cows, — **these put an end to all
>       kinds of sin** ( Parashara Smriti 12-80).

.

Comment: I don't think repentance resolves one from getting punished for bad karma , repentance saves one from punishment in hell and saves one from committing further bad karma . 
Once a person does bad Karma , he will have to bear its fruits , no matter what . 
eg- If you didn't study for a  exam , you will fail the exam for sure . Repentance will just ensure , you pass the exam in future.

Comment: Repenting from heart really clears the sins. The example you took is not exactly apt. But after repenting one has to resolve too that he won't commit the same sin again. That is the complete procedure. @river

Comment: But even Krishna got punished for his sin by getting killed from an arrow in his sole.
He could have repented for his sin and resolved himself from the punishment.

Comment: But how do we know that he had really repented? Also repent should be spontaneously done from the bottom of the heart. I think there is a procedure mentioned for it in some text.I will search for it @river

Answer (score 6):

There are various methods to expiate sins.

> **How to get rid of the effect of sins**
>
> Yudhisthira says,’…a perpetrated sin is expiated by auspicious acts, by publishing it wildly, by repentance, by alms-giving, by
>   penances, by trips to tirthas after renunciation of everything, by
>   constant meditation on the scriptures. Of all these, he that has
>   practiced renunciation is believed to be incapable of committing sins
>   anew. ‘

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section VII

Answer (score 3):

Saranagati(Self-Surrender) to SrimanNarayana is the easiest way to absolve oneself of all sins. This sentiment is aptly reflected in the following [verse](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-18-62.html) of Bhagavad Gita as expounded by Sri Krishna to Arjuna:

> सर्वधर्मान्परित्यज्य मामेकं शरणं व्रज।
>  अहं त्वा सर्वपापेभ्यो
>   मोक्षयिष्यामि मा शुचः।।18.66।।
>
> Sarva Dharmaan Parityajya Mamekam Sharanam Vraja|
>   Aham tva sarva papebhyo moksha ishyami ma shuchaha||
>
> *Meaning:*  **Relinquishing all notions of dharma, surrender yourself onto me alone and I shall deliver you from your sins. Knowing thus, Do not Grieve!**

Answer (score 1):

If you acquire true knowledge about Lord Krishna, that will release you of all sins (bad karma) as stated in the Bhagavad gita 10.3:
https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/3

> **He who knows Me** as the unborn, as the beginningless, as the Supreme
>   Lord of all the worlds – **he only, undeluded among men, is freed from
>   all sins**.

Answer (score -2):

Do Om Meditation Continually ,it slowly clear your sins and good for health.
As human beings, we have the ability to erase impression and fear through meditation. Meditation is there to rectify painful karma, at least reduce their impact or effect.

Links:

[Karma – the secret of dealing with it through meditation](https://www.artofliving.org/meditation/meditation-for-you/meditation-and-karma)

[How to clear Karma:The Meditative Way](http://www.inner-light-in.com/2012/08/how-to-clear-karma-the-meditative-way/)

Comment: DON'T FOLLOW THIS ADVICE. One should not chant pranava without getting initiation from guru. There are lot of rules and regulations for chanting it.. it is like nuclear power, should be dealt with carefully.

Comment: I am doing meditation on my own,didn't get any problem

Comment: The problem will not affect you, it affects whoever told you about pranava mantra. Even if you read it in a book, it affects whoever published that book for all to see.

Comment: be cautious, lot of politics here

Comment: what you call as politics is actually shastra.

Comment: @Kuhan What politics?