# What are the methods for doing repetance of sins?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, sin, manu-smriti

Most of us commit some sins in our day to day lives . What are the ways suggested in scriptures for repentance of sins.

Comment: See the Manu Smriti verse 11.227 given in the following answer. It answers your Q. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18644

Comment: Oh you want to know how exactly to repent? the procedure for it?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to repent. 
The link helped me a lot , it suggested doing charity to repentance.

Comment: Yes because in Kali Yuga the most effective method is charity.

Comment: So you want various method for destroying sins? or only the method of repenting? Repenting is one of the many methods of getting rid of sins. The answer you have accepted only gives the various methods how sins are removed and moreover it's already found in the link given above. And he has copy and pasted the same here.

Comment: @Rickross Both would be good i.e. destroying sin and repenting sin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to get rid of the effect of sins

> Yudhisthira says,’…a perpetrated sin is expiated by auspicious acts,
> by publishing it wildly, by repentance, by alms-giving, by penances,
> by trips to tirthas after renunciation of everything, by constant
> meditation on the scriptures. Of all these, he that has practiced
> renunciation is believed to be incapable of committing sins anew. ‘

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section VII**

Answer (score 2):

By chanting kshama Prathna which is succeeding text of Durga Saptashati.
You can find it [here](https://ia802802.us.archive.org/33/items/DurgaSaptsatiInPdf/durga%20saptsati%20in%20pdf.pdf). See page no. 275